# What is the difference between the framework and library?

Tags: javascript

How we can find the difference between the framework and library. All are confused with this topic.Please explain the differences of these two concepts in programmming language.

Comment: Hi hari satish, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can [edit] it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

Answer (score 0):

Library - A set of modules and functions that can be used within an existing project or app to extend its functionality and to help complete some part of your project. However, it is not necessary that a Library can help you make whole project.

For Example - You can use Jquery Library to add simple action effects on your project, but you still need to design the layout of your project manually, such as, Css and Html.

Framework - A framework is a complete solution, you can use it to create complete app without any external library.
Such as - Bootstrap.

Framework consists of many libraries.